# UPX doesn't work with -fPIE and ARM on Android

Tags: android, c++, static, android-ndk, upx

My multithreading C++ program, compiled with -static, doesn't work correctly on Android. If I compile it with -fPIE it does work as expected. I don't know the reason. My problem is that I can't compress the PIE executable with UPX because it says the executable format is unknown. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Regards

Comment: It's kind offtopic question. But why do you even use upx? For what purpose?

Comment: Could you please comment on what kind of error message you get etc?